# Can DataGridTextColumn use the MaxLength attribute somehow?

Tags: wpf

Is it somehow possible that the DataGrid (the DataGridTextColumn) of WPF uses the [MaxLength attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute?view=net-6.0) of a property?

I specify the MaxLength attribute for Entity Framework. But the attribute itself is part of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations (not of EF).

Is it possible? Or is it actually necessary to specify the length once for EF and once for WPF?

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Xyz" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Xyz}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="8"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is it actually necessary to specify the length once for EF and once for WPF?

Yes.

WPF doesn't check any data annotations for you.

You should set the `MaxLength` property of the `TextBox`.